# Keep Getting this error - Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, api, dart, model

I am trying to get an API and this error shows,
I am providing my API code

```
PeopleModel peopleModelFromJson(String str) => PeopleModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String peopleModelToJson(PeopleModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class PeopleModel {
    PeopleModel({
        this.page,
        this.perPage,
        this.total,
        this.totalPages,
        this.data,
        this.support,
    });

    int? page;
    int? perPage;
    int? total;
    int? totalPages;
    List<Datum>? data;
    Support? support;

    factory PeopleModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PeopleModel(
        page: json["page"],
        perPage: json["per_page"],
        total: json["total"],
        totalPages: json["total_pages"],
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
        support: Support.fromJson(json["support"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "page": page,
        "per_page": perPage,
        "total": total,
        "total_pages": totalPages,
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "support": support!.toJson(),
    };
}

class Datum {
    Datum({
        this.id,
        this.email,
        this.firstName,
        this.lastName,
        this.avatar,
    });

    int? id;
    String? email;
    String? firstName;
    String? lastName;
    String? avatar;

    factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        id: json["id"],
        email: json["email"],
        firstName: json["first_name"],
        lastName: json["last_name"],
        avatar: json["avatar"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "email": email,
        "first_name": firstName,
        "last_name": lastName,
        "avatar": avatar,
    };
}

class Support {
    Support({
        this.url,
        this.text,
    });

    String? url;
    String? text;

    factory Support.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Support(
        url: json["url"],
        text: json["text"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "url": url,
        "text": text,
    };
}
```

here is ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

My API code page //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    class PeopleService{
   List<PeopleModel> peoples = [];
   Future <List<PeopleModel>> getPeopleData()async{
        final url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';
        final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
           final List peopleList = jsonDecode(response.body);
           peoples = peopleList.map((e) =>PeopleModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
           
           print(response.body);
        }
        return peoples;
   }
}
```

this error shows in the console
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List'
any advise would helpfull

Comment: It means you are setting a _map_ as _list_.

Answer (score 0):

peoples is a List. `peopleList.map((e) =>PeopleModel.fromJson(e))` returns a Map. You can't just call .toList() on it and pass it to peoples directly. You should manipulate the data manually and fill peoples List.